# MongoDB - Combined multiple commands to send and return one request

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb

I'm currently using MongoDB in both PHP, and Javascript. What I would like to do is combined the following MongoDB commands in to one request, and then return it as one to avoid some of the errors that I have coming up in Javascript's AJAX. How would I go about it? Example of the commands (in Mongo form) I'd like to put in to one are below. Any help is appreciated!

```
db.colcName.find({"location": "London"})
db.colcName.count({"provider": "provider1"})
db.colcName.count({"provider": "provider2"})
db.colcName.count({"provider": "provider3"})
db.colcName.count({"provider": "provider4"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MongoDB's [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).

To compute the counts in your example in a single operation, use this:

```
db.colcName.aggregate([
   {"$match":{"location":"London"}},
   {"$group":{"_id":"$provider",
              "count":{"$sum":1}}}]);
```

This aggregation pipeline first selects only those records with "location" equal to "London", then it groups those records by the "provider" field (note the $ sign in front of the field name).  For each group, it computes the count (number of records).

Comment: I know what you mean but can you provide an example and not just a link and two unlinked words?

Comment: Sorry for being a bit terse there. Hope it's better now :)